# Parsing ISO 8601 like duration in Luxon

Tags: javascript, typescript, duration, luxon

I have duration string that looks like:

```
1:16.352
```

where `1` is minutes part, `16` is seconds part and `352` is millisecond part.

I wanted to use `Duration.fromISOTime` but I get:

```
{
  "reason": "unparsable",
  "explanation": "the input \"1:16.352\" can't be parsed as ISO 8601"
}
```

Is there a clean way of parsing such duration in Luxon?

Comment: @OlegValter afaik `Duration` does not have such method

Comment: apologies, I misread the question - how about `fromObject` method? Seems like you can split on a dot and use the values - or do you want to find a method that accepts custom formats directly?

Comment: `1:16.354` is neither a valid ISO-8601 time (`00:01:16.354`) or duration (`PT1M16.352S`) and cannot be parsed as if it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Duration.fromISOTime`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Times) does not work since `1:16.352` is **not** an ISO 8601 time string, the hour part is missing (see I[SO 8601 Times](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Times)).

A workaround to build a Luxon `Duration` object could be the following:

```js
const DateTime = luxon.DateTime;
const Duration = luxon.Duration;

const startOfHour = DateTime.local().startOf('hour').toMillis();
const dt = DateTime.fromFormat("1:16.352", "m:ss.SSS"). toMillis();
const dur = Duration.fromMillis(dt - startOfHour);
console.log(dur.toFormat("m 'minute' s 'second' S 'millis'"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@1.26.0/build/global/luxon.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Similarly to @VincenzoC I adjusted my input `string`:

```js
const Duration = luxon.Duration;

var output;
const durationInput = "1:16.352"

if (durationInput.match(/:/g) || [].length === 1) {
  const semicolonLocation = durationInput.indexOf(":");

  if (semicolonLocation === 1) {
    output = "00:0" + durationInput;
  }

  if (semicolonLocation === 2) {
    output = "00:" + durationInput;
  }
}

console.log(Duration.fromISOTime(output));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@1.26.0/build/global/luxon.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comments, you can use the [`fromObject`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/class/src/duration.js%7EDuration.html#static-method-fromObject) static method combined with simply splitting the input into `minutes`, `seconds`, and `milliseconds` configuration options. In your case a trivial regular expression `(\d+):(\d+)\.(\d+)` should do the trick, no temporary dates or normalization required.

```js
const { Duration } = luxon;
const durationInput = "1:16.352";

const fromCustom = (input) => {
  const [, minutes, seconds, milliseconds ] = input.match(/(\d+):(\d+)\.(\d+)/);
    
  return Duration.fromObject({
    minutes, seconds, milliseconds
  });
};

console.log(fromCustom(durationInput));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@1.26.0/build/global/luxon.js"></script>
```

Comment: there is only one case when regexp won't work - `1:16` without milliseconds part

Comment: @pixel - yep, obviously, I thought your input structure is stable? If not, then this `(\d+):(\d+)(?:\.(\d+))?` with a default to `milliseconds` should be more than enough afaik